# What is the normal length for a research paper?

Tags: publications, research-process, paper-submission, science, medicine

I did a survey on the demand for complementary medicine among patients of the gynaecologcial department here in Munich. We collected a couple of hundred questionnaires and I am currently writing my research paper. Since I do not know yet to which journal I am going to submit it, I wanted to adopt a very normal and standard structure/style. I was wondering now whether there are predefined standards of length concerning research papers, in particular regarding word count. I intuitively try to stay under 3000, but would it be ok to exceed that number? Moreover, is it fine to have, for example, a comparatively brief introduction and method section but a rather extensive discussion section? Or do the different sections have predefined standards too?

Comment: _One of them asked Lincoln, "How long should a man's legs be in proportion to his body?"  and Lincoln replied" "I have not given the matter much consideration, but on first blush I should judge they ought to be long enough to reach the ground."_ — Thomas Lawry, [_Personal Remembrances of Abraham Lincoln_](https://archive.org/stream/personalreminisc00lowr#page/22/mode/2up) (1910)

Comment: We cannot answer this without known which specific journal you are trying to publish. Also, most (all most all?) journals list length limits in the authors guidelines section.

Comment: My published papers range in length from 3 to 134 pages, and I don't consider any of them abnormal.

Comment: If you have a specific journal in mind -- why not just look at the articles in the past couple of years and average their lengths? Such data isn't very hard to find.

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to get a paper that you can publish in a journal, then it really depends on the journal, and if it has any specific requirements or constraints. There is no "standard" length for a paper. I've had papers that were 15 manuscript pages, and papers that were 50.

Comment: And it's very different between fields. In chemistry ~4 page papers are extremly common and all the raw data and experimental procedures are put into supplementary files.